# Is there a way to decode UTF-8 characters in @ARGV by default?

Tags: perl, utf-8, character-encoding

From what I understand, the `perl` interpreter does not automatically decode command-line arguments from terminal. This means, that if they contain wide characters, then one should handle them like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use I18N::Langinfo qw(langinfo CODESET);
use Encode qw(decode);
use Data::Dumper;

binmode STDOUT, ':utf8';

my $codeset = langinfo(CODESET); # returns 'UTF-8'

print Dumper \@ARGV;

foreach my $arg (@ARGV) {
    push @new_ARGV, decode $codeset, $arg;
}

# Now, the strings inside @new_ARGV are in valid internal format
print Dumper \@new_ARGV;
```

The above script gives result as following (the terminal and locale are set with `UTF-8`):

```
$ perl AC_351.pl śóą
$VAR1 = [
          'ÅÃ³Ä'
        ];
$VAR1 = [
          "\x{15b}\x{f3}\x{105}"
        ];
```

Should I always decode command-line arguments like this or is there some setting or switch to tell Perl to handle this by itself?

Comment: You can run `perl -CA`.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: Good find.